# Get Instagram profiles from email addresses?

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

I have a list of about 23,000 email addresses that belong to my customers.

I'm trying to find all the Instagram profiles that correspond to these email addresses.

What's the best way of doing that? I started learning to code recently and couldn't find that info anywhere. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Where is your code? What have you tried? Please be more specific. Low quality question, has been flagged.

Comment: Hey @toughskin, I haven't tried anything yet, not sure where to start..

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to access the usernames by email addresses through the API. Regardless of how you want to accomplish this. It cannot be done. Instagram does not allow access to email addresses in any way.